# How can i control event with 'if else' on Gtk#2.0

Tags: c#, user-interface, if-statement, events, text

I am new in C#. I work C# with monodevelop on linux. I created GUI and added label. I can control text of Label by button(When I click button, button's event changed text of label ). But I don't want use button. I want to run independently of the event(no button and no click, just use conditions). Is it possible to run the event don't use of any object event? I want to do that:

for example:

```
using System;
using Gtk;

public partial class MainWindow: Gtk.Window
{


public MainWindow () : base (Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
{

    Build (); 

}

protected void OnDeleteEvent (object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
{
    Application.Quit ();
    a.RetVal = true;

    int b = 5;
    if (b == 5) 
    {

    label2.Text="hello";
    }

    else label2.Text="world"; 
}
}
```

My goal is to change tags outside the event (eg: without using buttons). I searched but I couldn't find anything this. Thanks your time.

Best regards

Faruk

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Where do you want to use this `if/else` statement? In your `button click event`? When the form is loaded?  Somewhere else?  The logic seems fine, I just don't understand where you want to implement it.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What problem are you encountering?

Comment: Actually I read data from serialport and I want to write the incoming data to the GUI. I thought maybe I could do it with if /else

Comment: That sounds perfectly possible to do.  However it's still not clear what problem you're encountering when implementing it.  Can you tell us?

Comment: How can i change label's text. I want my data write on label's text. just I don't understand and couldn't this. or Do you have suggest? How can i incoming data write on to GUI

Comment: "Couldn't [do] this" is not descriptive, so we can't help.  Is it not building? Is it not updating? Is the incorrect label text being displayed?  Is no label text being displayed?  Etc.  If you explain what you are expecting to happen and what is actually happening, we may be able to help.

Comment: Ok. My label prop is 'label2'. If run code, I see 'label2' text on my GUI. I change this text.

Comment: Can you show the actual code?  Based on your "example" case, this should work for you

Comment: Edit my questio. I run code and I see Label prop name.

Comment: Does `OnDeleteEvent` actually fire?  Set a breakpoint if you are unsure

Comment: Thanks. I don't use  `OnDeleteEvent`.  I write my code below  `Build();` and work it.

Comment: If you are trying to change the label in a method that is never called, it will never change

Comment: Thanks your time @Greg and to everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer. If you want don't use event you should write code into `public MainWindow () : base (Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)`. Code this:

```
using System;
using Gtk;

public partial class MainWindow: Gtk.Window
{

public MainWindow () : base (Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
{
 Build (); 
  int b = 5;
    if (b == 5) 
    {
    label2.Text="hello";
    }
    else label2.Text="world"; 
}

  protected void OnDeleteEvent (object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
  {
    Application.Quit ();
    a.RetVal = true; 
   }
}
```

Thanks your time.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that there isn't a difference in the language when you're using monodevelop (i use vs) so I believe that your code should be working. I am just going to post my example:

```
int a = 2;
Label L = new Label();      //only for demonstration
if (a == 0)
{
    L.Text = "0";
}
else if (a == 1)
{
    L.Text = "1";
}
else
{
    L.Text = "else";
}
```

In my example, the Name of your label would be L

***EDIT***

I assume OP is working in WPF because my answer wasn't Fitting for him
In WPF only text-controls have the .Text property, all others use .Content
To make it more clear I added the WPF answertoo

```
int a = 2;
Label L = new Label();      //only for demonstration
if (a == 0)
{
    L.Content = "0";
}
else if (a == 1)
{
    L.Content = "1";
}
else
{
    L.Content = "else";
}
```

Comment: Hi, @Shmosi.  Unfortunately, what you wrote does not really provide an answer to the question.  The code you posted is almost exactly what OP wrote and you did not provide any explanation to further OP's understanding.

Comment: I wasn't exactly clear what he was asking for, but I assumed he wants an if/else statement and I just wanted to provide a quick answer :)

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. I dont' know which label's event should I use for this code.

Comment: I assume you are working in WPF, I updated my answer to fit WinForms and WPF